# is there a solution for conftest python file error

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting this error when I run `login_tests.py`

```
(venv) C:\Users\PRAGITI\PycharmProjects\lrtskodeit\tests>py.test Home/login_tests.py --browser chrome
ERROR: usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --browser chrome
  inifile: None
  rootdir: C:\Users\PRAGITI\PycharmProjects\lrtskodeit\tests

(venv) C:\Users\PRAGITI\PycharmProjects\lrtskodeit\tests>
```

Comment: Can we see longin_tests.py code? It's hard to say what is going wrong just by the output error.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I could ascertain that you have not added the command line argument "**browser**" in your `pytest.addoption()`.

However, IF the above solution is not useful, then it would be helpful if you provide your script content.